# Bad alloc in my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm having a RealTime application which displays on my Qt User Interface a value every second, without any problem. After around 4 minutes of displays, The project crashes and My project is heading to the following section in the file mlock.c

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
    int locknum
    )
{
    /*
     * leave the critical section.
     */

    LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Any idea what would be the problem and how to solve it?

Shall I call it a memory limit? In that case, there is no way to make it work for more than 4 minutes?

I shall find the provenance of the problem: it's written:

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
```

Edit:
If my main.cpp is as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
ex4 w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

and all of my vectors are declared in ex4.cpp file.
Do we consider that my vectors are global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post more, code? If you are using threads it might be a multi-threading issue, or you might be running out of memory.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Multithreads, I have edited my tags to OpenMP (pragma parallel, for sections ...). In that case I would get rid of their process in my project?

Comment: If you can get away with not using threads, it is probably better. Otherwise, if you can identify any suspicious pieces of code, post the code here -- somebody from SO might be able to help you then.

Comment: what was suspecious for me is the declaration of the 7 vectors of 1000, 1000 that I'm having. 7*1000*2 pointers multiplied by 4 minutes, it gives 336K pointer addresses!

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage you shouldn't post a comment as an answer

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage my inquiry will be: Do I have to declare those 7 matrices in the beginning of my project, or, declaring them in each function and delete them as soon as I finish dealing with them?

Comment: @spiritwolfform I agree with you 100%, but I couldn't find a way of adding a comment on the question. How do you do that?

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage you just press on : ADD COMMENT

Comment: @MelMed you can probably go either way, depending on your program design. Please try to post some code: I'm still not sure whether you have threading issue, or just running out of memory.

Comment: Which code can I post? I'm having thousands of lines.

Comment: I'm having for sure a lack of memory.
According to Out of Memory Handling in http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/exceptionsafety.html it says that QImage constructors will create a null image if not enough memory exists instead of throwing an exception, which is exactly my case.

Comment: @spiritwolfform I googled this a bit and it seems that I'm probably not going blind (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/cant-add-small-comments-to-questions). I'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: @MelMed, ok, then maybe just carefully go through your code and try to find your memory leak. Try to make your vectors globals, maybe that your leak.

Comment: Debug > Exceptions. Enable all the check boxes, run again, walk the callstack from where you catch the out of memory error.

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage I really believe my vectors are global.
Please see my edit above:

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage Shall I consider that on that case, they are not global?

Comment: @kfsone I' m having the array on ""LEAVE""

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where they are declared?

Comment: vector<array<double,1000>> S1(1000);
vector<array<double,1000>> S2(1000);
vector<array<double,1000>> TOT1(1000);